# Носитель защищен от записи Kingston SKC2000m8/500g

Tags: windows, установка, ssd, diskpart

Купил SSD Kingston SKC2000m8 / 500G на ноутбук Lenovo Legion Y720. Использовал его как системный, + был еще родной HDD на 1тб.

Работал нормально, но не прошло и года как в какой то момент вышел синий экран, и винда перестала загружаться

Теперь не получается установить винду на SSD, при установке установщику не удается отформатировать диск и вываливается ошибка 0x80042428.

Пытался исправить диск через diskpart. Удалял тома, менял с mbr на gpt и обратно.
При вводе `format fs=ntfs quick` вываливается ошибка:

```
Ошибка службы виртуальных дисков:
Носитель защищен от записи.
```

Пробовал также самому создавать Partition через тот же diskpart `create partition primary`, но увы результат такой же.
Так же поменял переменную регистре `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Control \ StorageDevicePolicies \ WriteProtect`, прочитал где-то, не помогло.

Подскажите, пожалуйста какие еще есть инструменты, которые я не пробовал. Диск почти новый, не хотел бы его так терять

Comment: У некоторых ssd есть такая фича, что они когда ломаются - переходят в read only, чтобы ты успел вытащить с них инфу. Так что я бы сначала нашёл бы чеки и качнул какую-нить фирменную тулзу для диагностики.